# Wordpress Advanced custom fields meta query filter in post object

Tags: wordpress

I have the following JSON format for event post type

[JSON Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIaIQ.png) 
[Event Channel Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xvi9.png) 
[Event Details Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbMXh.png)

I am trying to filter all upcoming events (i.e. future date) and having "Michael Kay" as an event_channel.

Below is my custom query and is not working. The issue is with the event_channel as it is a post object of 'channel' custom posts. The second portion of the meta query is not working.

```
<pre>
$today_r = date_i18n('j M Y g:i A');
$today = strtotime($today_r);  
    $upcoming_events = new WP_QUERY(array(
                        'post_type'         =>'event',          
                        'post_status'       => 'publish', 
                        'order'             => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
                        'meta_value'        => $today,
                        'meta_compare'      => '>=',
                        'meta_query'    => array(
                            'relation'      => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'event_start_date',
                                'value'     => $today,
                                'compare'   => '>=',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'relation'      => 'AND',
                                'key'       => 'event_channel',
                                    array(
                                        'key'       => 'post_title',
                                        'value'     => 'Michael Kay',
                                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',                                    
                                    ),
                            )
                        ),
                        "posts_per_page" => 6     
                    ));

</pre>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, describe more like what you want, what is the error etc...

Comment: The problem is how to get only events having "Michael Kay" as event_channel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust $args array. You should not pass post_title as meta key.
Use this one:

```
$upcoming_events = new WP_QUERY(array(
                        'post_type'         =>'event',          
                        'post_status'       => 'publish', 
                        'order'             => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
                        'meta_value'        => $today,
                        'meta_compare'      => '>=',
                        's' => 'Michael Kay',
                        "posts_per_page" => 6     
                    ));
```

Update:
Here is the query which filters it by ACF subfield:

```
$upcoming_events = new WP_QUERY(array(
                        'post_type'         =>'event',          
                        'post_status'       => 'publish', 
                        'order'             => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_key'          => 'event_start_date',
                        'meta_value'        => $today,
                        'meta_compare'      => '>=',
                        'meta_query'    => array(
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'event_channel_0_post_title',
                                'value'     => 'Michael Kay',
                                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                            ),
                           )));
```

To know exact correct name of your event_channel_0_post_title key, go to PHPMYADMIN->wp_postmeta table, and search for "Michael Kay" there. You will see correct name there if event_channel_0_post_title is incorrect.

Comment: This query is only working when the 's' term is in Event Title but not filtering by the event_channel (See attached image in question). Any solutions?

Comment: i don't know the exact structure of your ACF. But you can try the one which i am adding to my answer now. check it

Comment: Hi @Elvin - It's still not working for me. Please see attached images for your reference. Would love to hear more options from you. Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't attached anything from MySQL, which is required in this case

Comment: Hi @Elvin - In database there is only "meta_key" as event_channel and "meta_value" as ID of that event_channel as in JSON Format attached in question.

Comment: Then replace event_channel_0_post_title with event_channel in my last code. It is not ideal solution, but would fit to your need

Comment: I already tried this. event_channel has values in the array (see attached JSON) this is the main concern.